# Booking logic and architecture, database sync: Hotels, tennis courts reservation system 

Tags: database, architecture, synchronization

Imagine that you want to design a tennis booking system.
You have 5 tennis clubs as partners with no online api allowing you to check on their side if a court is booked or not: You have to build this part as well.

Every time a booking is done on their side you want it to be known by our system. Probably using a POST request form tennis partner to our server.

Every time a booking is done on our website, we want to push the booking to their system. The difficulty is that their system need to be online and accessible from outside. Ip may change, we have to use a dns updater.

In case their system is not available we still accept the booking and fallback to an async email with 'i confirm booking/reject booking' link sent to the club.

I find the whole process quite complex and was wondering about the way online hotel booking system and hotel were working. Do they all have their data open and online ?

The good thing is that the data will grow large and fits nicely to some no SQL ;) like couch db

Comment: Actually, this seems like an excellent fit for a relational database, and a poor fit for a document-oriented database.

Comment: Are you concerned about a relational database handling datasets that small?  Admittedly, most databases are much, much larger, but I'm pretty sure most relational database servers can scale down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several questions here, let me try and address each one...

Since this appears to be an internet application with federated servers, using the implied HTTP Protocol makes a lot of sense. This could be done via Form POSTs, GET, or even REST-ful submission of some custom data structure. In the end, the exact approach to use will need to come down to the size and complexity of the information being communicated. Many architectures employ these approaches and often combine them with encrypted, signed, and/or encoded payloads for security. One short-fall to consider with these approaches is that they will require you to clearly communicate all request / response message formats, field ranges, and variations since these mechanisms are not really self-describing. On the other hand, these patterns use very common protocols, are easily understood, easy to implemented, and are typically lean on-the-wire.

In constrast, architectures with very complex structures often chose to use WSDL-based web services.  Also driven by common standards, these tend to be self-describing, inherently versionable, although they can take more time and energy to implement. There are a lot of advantanges to web services which are driven by many WS-* standards which may be worth investigating further in your case.

As for the reservation process... many similar architectures will employ an orchestration model such as the following:

- Find open booking spaces
- Make a reservation for a booking space. This places an expiring lock on a space while the requestor fills in all required booking information. This mitigates against race conditions that could lead to multiple bookings for the same space
- Once all required booking information is received and validated the booking is confirmed and permamently locked from use by other requestors

As for the SQL-style DB comment, I can't really say given the amount of information supplied. With that said, my instincts tell me a SQL-style DB is completely reasonable for this problem set. I have databases with many pedabytes and have very high SLA's. You implied a need for high availability and SQL-based databases have a few decades of proven support behind them in this area.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find most on-line hotel reservation systems aren't really on-line. My experience is that those companies (not the hotels themselves) offering on-line booking systems also insist that the hotel itself also books their rooms on-line using the same system.

Everything works fine as long as connectivity is not an issue - and in small motels scenario it normally will. Of course the bigger hotels use the same system the airlines do and they have dedicated communications links for the purpose. The reservations are of course maintained on one central computer with appropriate backup links etc etc etc.

It is very easy for individual tennis clubs to offer their own real-time online booking systems using their own database/website with programs like [MyCourts](http://www.mycourts.com.au) offers however once you want to link more than one clubs facilities then you really don't have much option other than to have a centralized server that both the user and the club both have to use to reserve facilities.